# VBA for loop for multiple variables when variable is an array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, variables, for-loop

I have a function

```
Range("M32") = Range("D26").Value
```

that I want to loop around in a for loop using m = [Range("M32") Range("M40)] and d = [Range("D26") Range("D30")] however im not sure what the correct syntax would be for VBA

The only way I can determine to do a multiple variable for loop is

```
for m = 1 to 2
    for d = 1 to 2
          m = d.Value
```

but that is not working

I want it to be more like

```
for m = 1 to 2 and d = 1 to 2
```

so when m references the 1st item in its array d also only references the 1st item in its array. Does vba do that sort of thing? I also have several other variables id like to add along with m and d

Comment: You can use only one loop and one counter if your two arrays have the same size. You can also try `Range("M32:M40").value = Range("D26:D34").value`

Answer (score 0):

You can use one loop and just do the math for the row numbers directly in Range. In the Range callout, you can use **&** followed by a number to construct a string which references your cell:

```
For i = 0 to 8
    Range("M" & i + 32).Value = Range("D" & i + 26).Value
Next i
```

In this example, starting with 0, you will be setting the value of the cell M32 to the value in D26. Then i increments by 1, so M33 gets set to D27... and so on until you reach i = 8, or the value in M40 = the value in D34